# I want to have a new environment with 7 arguments. What is the problem here?

Tags: latex

I want to have a new environment with 7 arguments. What is the problem here? Please help. Each time it is showing error: *"llegal character in array arg." and "You can't use `macro parameter character #' in restricted horizontal mode."*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in, a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{bengali}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali]{Kalpurush}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{}
\makeatother

    
\newenvironment{word}[8]% environment name
{
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c}
\fbox{#1} & \textit{#2} & --- & \multicolumn{4}{#3}\\
& & & \multicolumn{4}{#4}\\
\hline
& & & #5 & #6 & #7 & #8\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
{}


\title{Words}
\author{}
\date{January 2023}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{11/01/2023}

\begin{word}{654}{respite}{A (temporary) relief from harm or discomfort/A pause for relaxation/The art of reprieving; postpone or remitting punishment}{}{}{}{}{}\end{word}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax `\multicolumn{...}{...}` is wrong. `\multicolumn` has three mandatory arguments, not just two.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in, a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{comment}
%\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\setmainlanguage{english}
%\setotherlanguage{bengali}
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
%\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali]{Kalpurush}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{}
\makeatother

\NewDocumentEnvironment{word}{mmmmmmmm}{
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c}
\fbox{#1} & \textit{#2} & --- & \multicolumn{4}{p{6cm}}{#3}\\
& & & \multicolumn{4}{c}{#4}\\
\hline
& & & #5 & #6 & #7 & #8\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
{}


\title{Words}
\author{}
\date{January 2023}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{11/01/2023}

\begin{word}{654}{respite}{A (temporary) relief from harm or discomfort/A pause for relaxation/The art of reprieving; postpone or remitting punishment}{}{}{}{}{}\end{word}

\end{document}
```

[image]